# IntelliJ Spring Library is not downloaded

Tags: intellij-idea

The install of intellij SpringFramework Project is failing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96Ssk.png)

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a known issue. Please follow [this YouTrack ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-230778) to stay updated on the progress toward solution.

Take a look at [this article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241135) if you are not familiar with YouTrack.